# as MySQL root user: how to switch to other user without password

Tags: mysql, sql, authentication, authorization, sql-grant

In UNIX root user can do

```
su - tme34
```

without password. So he can test tme34 account. Howto do the same in MySQL?
I don't know other MySQL users password and don't wish to reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. However, you could add another user with the same username and different host.

If the current user has a wildcard host `%` you can add another one with your current IP address (or `localhost` if you are on mysql's machine) and they will coexist. You can then login from the command line and your matching IP will use that new user instead of the existing one.